# background worker cannot read variable from other form

Tags: vb.net, variables, backgroundworker

I have my main form, called home.

Home has a public variable called 'activeuser'.
This variable is a string that literally has a users name in it, for example "John Smith".

One of my other forms, 'caseupdate', has a background worker which is fired by a timer.
This background worker checks against a MySQL db to look for new records, specifically ones which are "assigned" to the user who is logged on.

I figured this would be simple and in my SQL statement, I just did...

```
    dim currentuser as string = home.activeuser
```

This didn't work at all and I'm at a loss as to how I can get the username value into the background worker to make everything work.

Any help appriciated! :)

Comment: First, your description not entirely makes sense. You need to set something for `DoWork` before BGW starts. No, BGW can't read from another thread - it only gives feedback.

Comment: apologies, I should have been more clear.
the BGW code is in the DoWork bit.

I have a timer which checks if the bgq is busy and if not, runs 'CaseListUpdater.RunWorkerAsync()'.

So how would you get the bit of information from a variable in a random form into the background worker?

Comment: It would be best to define `activeuser` in a module:
`Public activeuser as String`

And make the assignment after the login:
`activeuser = "John Smith"`

`activeuser` be visible in any form of the project.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? Did you have an error message? A way for threads to communicate with other threads is to use events.

Comment: so by didnt work i mean that the SQL query pulls back no records because instead of having 'WHERE assignedto =John Smith', it has 'WHERE assignedto =""'.

Comment: Can anyone point me in the right direction for using a module?
I'm more of a hobbyist than anything else and I'm not familiar...

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Me.RunWorker()
End Sub

Private Sub RunWorker()
    If Not Worker.IsBusy Then
        Me.Worker.RunWorkerAsync("Pablo")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles Worker.DoWork
    Dim result As Boolean
    If e.Argument = "root" Then
        result = True
    Else
        result = False
    End If
    e.Result = result
End Sub

Private Sub Worker_Completed(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles Worker.RunWorkerCompleted
    MsgBox(e.Result)
End Sub
```